# cant get div to touch bottom of the screen. e,g height is not 100%

Tags: css, html

I am looking to fix the div that says 'this div' everything is touching the bottom except for this one div and that is because i have 2 divs above it with the logo and icons etc, it pushes 'this div' out by 100 pixels or so.

http://2click4.com/message3.php

here is the link

```
#msg_names {
    height: 100% !important;
    height: 100%;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    position: relative;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    width:150px;
}
```

this is my css for the div

Comment: The "this div" in your example does touch the bottom of the window on my computer.

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: it doesnt on mine, it hangs over by like 50 - 100px, dtdesign i clearly need it to touch the bottom of the window..

Comment: Actually, this is a typical question about stretching the inner block to its container height. You set the height of the container to 100%, which means, its parent would have this msg_names block height, plus 'opt' and 'search' heights, which would cause such behavior.

Answer (score -1):

Try changing the "container" div position from "absolute" to "fixed", like this:-

```
#container {
width: 100%;
min-width: 600px;
height: 100%;
min-height: 100%;
position: fixed;
}
```

Comment: Have you really tried this solving by your own on the page provided? That does not work.

Comment: Yes i have tried it and it was working perfectly.

Comment: Well, not exactly. That's why I put "-1". If you do that, you don't see the scroll bar, for sure. But still, the msg_names container have a height which equals 100% of its container height and if it have any content, some part of it would be just hidden at the bottom.